# Improve performance of cleaning function

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, asynchronous

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to understand what is the best approach to fasten a cleaning function. (can I use multiprocessing? asynchronous functions? split this function in smaller functions and use multithreading?)

```
def clean(s):
"""
:param s: string to be processed
:return: processed string: see comments in the source code for more info
"""
   s = re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1\. \2', s)  # before lower case
   s = s.lower()
   s = re.sub(r'etc\.?','',s)
   s = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', ' ', s)
   s = re.sub(r'(on?\s?\d+\s?\.?\:?\d*\s?am)|(on?\s?\d+\s?\.?\:?\d*\s?pm)','',s)
   s = re.sub(r'(at?\s?\d+\s?\.?\:?\d*\s?am)|(at?\s?\d+\s?\.?\:?\d*\s?pm)','',s)
   s = re.sub(r'[^\D+\s?]', ' ',s)
   s = re.sub(r'^\-\s?', '',s)
   s = re.sub(r'[$€£]+', '',s)
   s = re.sub(r'(\s+\-\s+)', ' ',s)
   s = re.sub(r'(\,+\s?\,?)', ',',s)
   s = re.sub(r'\#+', ' ',s)
   s = re.sub(r'[.!]+', '.',s)
   s = re.sub(r'\s?\&+\s?', ' and ', s)
   s = re.sub(r'([a-z])\1{2,}', r'\1', s)
   s = re.sub(r'([\W+])\1{1,}', r'\1', s)
   s = re.sub(r'\*|\W\*|\*\W', '', s)
   s = re.sub(r'\W+?\.', '.', s)
   s = re.sub(r'(\.|\?|!)(\w)', r'\1 \2', s)
   s = re.sub(r'(.{2,}?)\1{1,}', r'\1', s)
   s = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', s)
   s = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)','',s)
return s.strip()

df['Sentences'].apply(clean)
```

Thanks for your Help

Comment: please note that you missed the indent of the function body. You could potentially use `threading` which is similar, but not the same as multiprocessing. However, given that you need to do all the operations, you might already be at the fastest case.

Comment: Threading or multiprocessing won't help with an inherently serial operation like this. If there was an `apply` version that would run each application in a subprocess, it might help.

Comment: One thing you could do to speed up your code is to use `.str`-operations instead of using `.apply`. For example: `df.Sentences.str.replace(r"([a-z])([A-Z])", r"\1\. \2", regex=True)` ...

Comment: @AKX thanks, how would you create an apply version of this?
@Timus how would this improve the speed? Because I would still need to create a `.replace()` for each line?

Comment: Some of the separate remove-this-and-that-completely lines could probably be merged. The on-at am-pm lines too, they also misuse `?`, it applies to `n` and `t` only. I think a single `(on|at)? ... (am|pm)` could do the job of those 2 lines. The `\(.*?\)` removed parentheses already, the very last regex will unlikely find more.

Comment: @QuentinMahieu `apply` isn't very fast, definitely not vectorized. [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html): _"Vectorized string functions for Series and Index."_ I've measured the speed gain for a couple of steps: Takes on average only half the time. That's not a huge step, but better than nothing :)